# ng-view don't get replaced by html

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I have configure the route in app.js: and my root path is `http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin`. so when i click on the #/stock/new, it goes to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin#/stock/new`. is it correct?

```
var aomaika = angular.module('aomaika', ['ngRoute']);

aomaika.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/stock/new', { templateUrl: 'partials/new.html', controller: 'StockNewCtrl'})
    .when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/index.html', controller: 'DashboardCtrl'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

and in index.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang="en" ng-app='aomaika')
    head
        title= title
        meta(name='description', content='overview &amp; stats')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')

        script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js')
        script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular-resource.min.js')
        script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js')
        script(src="js/app.js")
        script(src="js/controllers.js")
        script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js")

    body(ng-controller="StockCtrl")
        div#main-container.main-container
            a(href="#/stock/new") New Stock
            div(ng-view)
```

but when click on New Stock as #/stock/new, the partials/new.html don't insert into the ng-view. what's going on? and why there is a "#" before /stock/new. what's that?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `StockCtrl` but in your JS you're referencing `StockNewCtrl`.

And where is your controller code ?

And please, just put the compiled HTML, not jade code ...